# ADO Command Execute fails

Tags: c++, networking, ado

I am using Execute method on the ADO command object to execute a stored procedure. This call throws an exception when the network adapter is disabled and re-enabled

why would the Execute fail in this case ?

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: @jbl why would the Execute fail in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

The Execute fails because the underlying network connection has been lost (though the logical state of the Connection object will still appear as Open)

What you can do about this :

- as a general rule, open your connection just before using it. Release it just after use,
- have an error handling process which, on error, checks if the connection is closed, reopens it and rerun the Command.

I guess the answer depends on your use of your DB.
You could also imagine having a monitorig thread which performs simple select on a regular basis and reopens the connection if it is closed.

Comment: This helps.The connection object said it was 'open' but actually it was not.Probably, I will reinitialize the connection to make it work.Thanks for the tip..